# cannot use heroku CLI due to previously configured file `cacert.pem`

Tags: amazon-s3, ssl-certificate, heroku-cli

```
leder@home-ryzen:~/Git/ghost-v4-on-heroku-burzltag$ heroku certs:remove --name cacert.pem
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.60.1 to 8.7.1.
 ▸    ENOENT: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/leder/Source/pfhp_production_heroku/cacert.pem'
```

every heroku CLI command complains about missing `cacert.pem`: I cannot remove the certificate from heroku!

I ran
`heroku apps`
`heroku certs:remove ...`
and
`heroku config:set SSL_CERT_FILE=/home/leder/Source/pfhp_production_heroku/config/global-bundle.pem`

in order to use the AWS SSL certificate with heroku. How do I get heroku back to work on CLI?

Answer (score 0):

resolved by removing the following line from `.bashrc`:

```
#export SSL_CERT_FILE=~/Source/pfhp_production_heroku/cacert.pem
```